# Output in Label instead of MessageBox

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                int a, b;
                bool prime = true;
                a = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                b = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);


                int i = a;
                while (i < b)
                {
                    for (int j = 2; j <= i; j++)
                    {
                        if (i != j && i % j == 0)
                        {
                            prime = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (prime)
                    {
                        string ans = i.ToString();
                        MessageBox.Show(ans);
                    }
                    prime = true;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The program displays prime number from start (textbox1) to end (textbox2)
You can input any number in both textboxes and it will display the prime numbers in the given range that is inputted by the user in textbox1 and textbox2. My problem is that how can I put the output in label instead of MessageBox?
Its output only displays one number, it can't display more than one number whenever I change

```
MessageBox.Show(ans);
```

TO

```
label4.Text = ans;
```

and

```
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
```

TO

```
label4.Text=ex.Message;
```

I only used one label which is `label4`. Please help.

Comment: Add a label to your form and set its `Text` property.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, it's not that you are having trouble figuring out how to set the `Label.Text` property itself, but rather that you are having trouble having more than one number being displayed at a time.

Unfortunately, your question doesn't show us what you've tried with respect to achieving that goal. I.e. the code you posted still uses `MessageBox`, rather than whatever other attempt you've made (unsuccessfully) to achieve your goal. So it's hard to know what would be a desirable or even acceptable approach.

One option is to just put all the computed numbers into a single `Label` control. For example:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            int a, b;
            bool prime = true;
            List<int> results = new List<int>();

            a = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            b = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);

            int i = a;
            while (i < b)
            {
                for (int j = 2; j <= i; j++)
                {
                    if (i != j && i % j == 0)
                    {
                        prime = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (prime)
                {
                    results.Add(i);
                }
                prime = true;
                i++;
            }

            label1.Text = string.Join(", ", results);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, maybe you do want each number displayed individually, but you want the code to present the number long enough for the user to see it before moving on to the next:

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            int a, b;
            bool prime = true;

            a = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            b = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);

            int i = a;
            while (i < b)
            {
                for (int j = 2; j <= i; j++)
                {
                    if (i != j && i % j == 0)
                    {
                        prime = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (prime)
                {
                    label1.Text = i.ToString();
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                }
                prime = true;
                i++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Those are just two of a wide range of plausible options. For example, you might want to show the results in a `ListBox`, or a scrollable, multiline `TextBox`. If neither of the above address your concern, please edit your question so that it more clearly explains what you've tried and what it is exactly you want the code to do.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

1. Add a `Label` control to your form named `MyLabel`. (Or it could be any name)
2. Change `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);` to `MyLabel.Text = ex.Message;`

Answer (score 0):

Add a label  to your form and simply put (assuming it is named label1)

```
label1.Text=ans;
```

[.Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cs4xb3d(v=vs.110).aspx) is a property of most controls.
You are already using the 'get' accessor of your textboxes in your integer parsing.  Text defines a 'set', which you can use in your c# to change the text you are displaying.

Read more on properties [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) as they are used extensively in c#