# C# Empty Textbox Validation

Tags: c#, validation, textbox

My Form has 6 textboxes and I want to validate empty textbox. I found this code in another post. How can I use this code to display label message for each empty textbox and save data to my database if all textbox are filled?

I added image to get some idea what I want to achieve. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qy4NH.png)

```cs
if(this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Any(t => string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Text)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This will return `true` if one of your `TextBox`es is empty. You can use `var emptyTextboxes = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(t => string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Text));`, then iterate over them and print your labels.

Comment: You can use `MessageBox.Show("Cannot be empty")`. Or if you do not want that messagebox and want label, check the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33859988/output-in-label-instead-of-msgbox

Comment: Suggestion. Read some manuals about texboxes and labels, lean how they work. Do not copy/paste code if you don't understand it - that's the biggest mistakes people do. The result is usual - something not working and have no idea what is wrong.